# Additional Tutorials or worked examples of best practice for configuring multi vm projects in google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was hoping people would know of more samples and best practice guides for configuring systems on google compute engine so I can gain more experience in deploying them and apply the knowledge to my own projects.

I had a look at https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/samples-and-videos#samples which runs through deploying cassendra cluster and hadoop using scripts but I was hoping there might be more available including on the following topics

- Load balancing webservers across zones samples including configuring networking,
  firewalls and load balancer.
- Fronting tomcat servers with apache behind a load balancer
- Multi network systems in compute engine using subnetting
- Multi project systems and how to structure them for reliability and secure interoperability.

They would be easy to follow projects you build starting from a blank project and end up with a sample site running across multiple vm's & zones with recommended security in place, a bit like the videos you see for gae coding examples that go from hello world to something more complex but for infrastructure not code.

Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout https://cloud.google.com/developers/#resources for tutorial and samples as well as http://googlecloudplatform.github.io

I'm new to the forums so I can only post two links. Taking a quick look I see several topics that may be of interest to you:

- Managing Hadoop Clusters on Compute Engine
- Auto Scaling on the Google Cloud Platform
- Apache Hadoop, Hive, and Pig on Google Compute Engine
- Compute Engine Load Balancing in Action

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks they are useful & have read some of them before but I'd really like to find more examples or recommended patterns that a user could use as a reference when designing their own systems to run on GCE for example I run vm's on physical hosts but the networks people have already setup the VLAN's for me. If I want to create a test environment in GCE that modeled a subset of our physical setup that needs 2 vlans (mgmt & storage for eg) whats the best way to start. Do I build 1 monolithic project that includes everything or separate it out into different projects 1 for mgmt & 1 for storage?